# How initialize data in TestNG and provide it to business method without passing as parameter?

Tags: java, testng

I am writing the first time TestNG test cases. I have done some basics. Now I have to write test cases for some complex business logic. So the requirement is, I make the connection with the database and fetch some data after that I write that data on CSV file. The file name comes from a property file which we load and store in a Map at the time of server startup. So writing `Constants.getProperty("KEY");` returns me the name of the file. How can I execute the same code when the server is shutdown. Is there any way I can initialize this Constant's map in TestNG and application can get the reference of the same. For example,

```
 public String getAndWriteData(){
    Connection con = OracleUtil.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
     rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
     String directory = Constants.getProperty("DIRECTORY_NAME");
     String fileName = Constants.getProperty("FILE_NAME");
     /*
       Constants is a class which has a Map. When tomcat server gets start, 
       it loads all the property into Map. So when tomcat is running the 
       Constants is availabe. But when I execute TestCases at the time of
       building war same property is not available as tomcat is not started.
     */
     File targetFile = new File(directory + File.separator + fileName);
     FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(targetFile);
     writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
     while (rs.next()) {
            //Writing data on CSV
        }
 }
```

Comment: Please add a bit more context to your question in the from of some pseudo code etc., so that it makes it easy for us to understand what you are trying.

Comment: Are you doing unit tests or integration tests? For the first case you probably should change your design and separate business logic from data read/write (and mock read/write logic). For the second case you probably should actually have a full setup. Also consider usage of IOC aka "Inversion Of Control" and "Dependency Injection"